# MySQL Return different value if it doesn't exist in another table

Tags: mysql

I have `items` and `lists` tables which store items and lists respectively. I'm trying to retrieve all items in a particular list identified by `url`. `url` is a unique key in `lists`.

```
SELECT 
    items.item_name,
    items.position,
    items.checked,
    lists.list_name
FROM 
    items 
JOIN lists
WHERE 
    items.list_id=lists.list_id AND lists.url=?
ORDER BY items.position
```

This works, but I want to differentiate a case where

1. `lists.url` does not exist in `lists` and
2. it exists in `lists`, but the list does not contain any items.

Currently, this query returns an empty set on both cases. What is a good way to do this in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select`lists` and `LEFT JOIN` `items`.

```
SELECT items.item_name,
       items.position,
       items.checked,
       lists.list_name
FROM lists
LEFT JOIN items ON items.list_id=lists.list_id 
WHERE lists.url=?
ORDER BY items.position
```

You will get single row if list exists but has no items. The items fields will be `NULL`.

Comment: I like this. Do you know why it has to select from lists and do a join on items instead of the other way around? EDIT: Actually, that is something I can learn by googling. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Because you want to retrieve `lists` row no matter if `items` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join:

```
SELECT 
  items.item_name,
  items.position,
  items.checked,
  lists.list_name 
FROM lists
LEFT JOIN items ON lists.list_id=items.list_id
WHERE lists.url=?
ORDER BY items.position
```

This will return an empty result-set if the list doesn't exist and if the list is empty it will return the list_name and all item-fields will be null.

Comment: I think you meant Select from `lists` and LEFT JOIN `items` as dragoste posted. When I tried your query, they both return an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if exists` to differentiate your results,

like:

```
   IF EXISTS(SELECT * from lists where lists.url=@urlid) THEN
   BEGIN

    SELECT items.item_name,items.position,items.checked,lists.list_name
    FROM items JOIN lists
    WHERE items.list_id=lists.list_id AND lists.url=?
    ORDER BY items.position
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
   // Return something else to differential that urlid is invalid. like Select 0
  END
```

For second situation you can use count query inside first if to know if no results exist.